# How to remove oxide layer around stainless steel welds with household items

Tags: materials, steel, welding

I have a stainless steel pot whose welds show the formation of an oxide layer. Colors around those welds range from gold to dark blue (see images below). The main question is: How do I remove those oxide layers with household items? I assume the standard process would be pickling those welds, is that right?

Am I too concerned? As far as google brought me, discoloration due to welding is acceptable up to shades of gold but dark blue should definitely not occur (e.g. in regarding corrosion resistance).

[image: Weld 1]
[image: Weld 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oxide color layers shown are of no concern. The colors are caused by thickness of oxide , however they are only a few to several layers thick. Household items that will remove them are sand paper and possibly steel wool.

Comment: Would citric acid also be suitable?

Comment: @BigX Just use Scotch Brite.